# I/O file stream C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    string temp;

    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    inFile.open("ZRMK Matched - 010513.txt");
    outFile.open("second.txt");

    while(!inFile.eof()) {  

        getline(inFile, temp);
        if (temp != "") {
            getline(inFile, temp);
            outFile << temp;
        }
    }

    cout << "Data Transfer Finished" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm having difficulty getting this to work. When I execute the program it cycles for awhile and then terminates without finishing -- it doesn't output any lines of text to the output file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you used the debugger?  Does it output your "Data Transfer Finished" message?

Comment: Have you tried flushing the outfile?

Comment: Is the fact that you call getline twice per iteration (first to check `(temp != "")` and second to write to outfile) intentional?

Comment: Are you trying to copy every second line in `inFile` to `outFile`? Also, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14615671/150634).

Comment: It would help the cause of analyzing your problem *tremendously* if we know (a) what your program is *supposed* to do, (b) what the input data looks like, and (c) why you think your code *should* work but doesn't *seem to*.

Comment: The is probably not your immediate problem, but you should never use `.eof()` in a loop condition. Doing so almost always results in a buggy program.

Comment: To repeat what the previous comment says, **DO NOT WRITE `while(!inFile.eof())`, THAT IS NOT HOW TO READ FROM A STREAM**

Comment: Do not copy files; let your operating system do that.  Operating Systems are generally more efficient at file manipulation than your program.  After all, your program invokes OS functions for file manipulation.

Comment: Why are you including <string> AND <cstring> ? Isn't <string> enough ? Also, you should close the opened streams.

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to copy every line?

```
while(std::getline(inFile, temp)) {
  outFile << temp << "\n";
}
```

Are you trying to copy every non-blank line?

```
while(std::getline(inFile, temp)) {
  if(temp != "")
    outFile << temp << "\n";
}
```

Are you trying to copy every 2nd non-blank line?

```
int count = 0;
while(std::getline(inFile, temp)) {
  if(temp == "")
    continue;
  count++;
  if(count % 2)
    outFile << temp << "\n";
}
```

Are you simply trying to copy the entire file?

```
outFile << inFile.rdbuf();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a mode to open files : see [std::ios_base::openmode](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/openmode/)
And don't forget to close the streams you open !
You can even try catch your code to understand the problem if an exception occurred.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    try {
        fstream inFile;
        fstream outFile;

        // open to read
        inFile.open("ZRMK Matched - 010513.txt", ios_base::in); 
        if (!inFile.is_open()) {
            cerr << "inFile is not open ! " << endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        // Open to append
        outFile.open("second.txt", ios_base::app); 
        if (!inFile.is_open()) {
            cerr << "inFile is not open ! " << endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        string line;
        while(getline(inFile, line)) {  
            if (!line.empty()) {
                outFile << line << endl;
            }
        }

        if (outFile.is_open()) {
            outFile.close(); // Close the stream if it's open
        }
        if (inFile.is_open()) {
            inFile.close(); // Close the stream if open
        }

        cout << "Data Transfer Finished" << endl;
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    } catch (const exception& e) {
        cerr << "Exception occurred : " << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```