# How to read-and-validate from istringstream by fields

Tags: c++, parsing, istream

I am trying to check input validity. I am given a file, where there are two columns, first one of strings, second one of ints. The separator is any number of spaces. The problem is, I cannot figure out how to properly check if the second item really is an int. Consider this code:

```
string line; // parameter with a string to be parsed
string name;
int num;
istringstream lineStream(line);
lineStream >> name;
lineStream >> num;
```

by calling `lineStream.good()` I can detect inputs such as "abcd g", but when I put something like "abcd 12a" in, it is parsed to "abcd" and 12. Same with "abcd 12.2" etc.

In Java I could use `String.split()` to an array and then parse each whole element, not ignoring any characters, but I do not know what is the correct approach here.

Thanks for hints

Comment: You can effect the same "split" strategy in C++ assuming your split is based on whitespace into strings, then validate the individual entities, but ultimately the question is a fair point. It seems you're asking how to validate the *element* being extracted is, in fact, complete and concise, and perhaps how to glean that information via stream properties. Good question. I'll be interested in different approaches to this.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to do this simply, i.e. using streams. One could hassle with creating an array of char*, then tokenize them and check validity, that's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply check if you reached the end of the line `std::stringstream` after you've extracted the `int`. If the `int` extraction fails, there was no integer at all. If it succeeds but there is still content in the stream, then there is too much in the line. I would approach the problem like so:

```
std::string line, name;
int num;
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
  std::stringstream line_stream(line);
  if (line_stream >> name >> num &&
      line_stream.eof()) {
    // Line was of the correct format
  }
}
```

Basically, there are two checks:

1. `line_stream >> name >> num` will fail if it can't extract either the `string` or `int`.
2. After these extractions, the `eof` bit will be set if they reached the end of the stream. So `line_stream.eof()` will fail if there is still content left in the stream.

Obviously this is a pretty fragile method that only works for the particular situation and would need adapting to pretty much any change in line format.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That's a [common misconception](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14615671/150634) (almost as common as thinking `!eof()` is a good `while` condition). `eof` is set when the extraction reaches the end - it's just not a good condition to use before reading.

Comment: This won't work if there are any whitespaces after the second field, will it?

Comment: @MartinMelka Indeed it won't. It'll only allow specifically `<somestring> <whitespace> <int>`. Do you want to allow whitespace at the end?

Comment: I think I do. Maybe if I called `line_stream >> somestring` in the end, it would consume the whitespaces and therefore moved to an eof? (I could then check whether `somestring.length()==0` to eliminate the possibility of an another stuff in the stream) ?

Comment: @MartinMelka That sounds plausible.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That's a different situation. Because you're extracting a `char`, it only reads a single character and doesn't hit the end. When extracting an `int`, it keeps reading until it hits the end of file and then sets the eof bit. Using `!eof()` fails when you haven't hit the end yet your next extraction will fail anyway - such as with a text file (which has a hidden extra `\n` at the end).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I agree. I've rephrased the last sentence to make that a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can read two strings and then check if second string is realy a number. Something like this:

```
std::string line; // parameter with a string to be parsed
std::string name;
std::string strNum;
int num;
std::istringstream lineStream(line);
lineStream >> name;
lineStream >> strNum;

if (isNumber(strNum))
{
   num = atoi(strNum.c_str());
}

//

bool isNumber(const std::string& strNum)
{
   bool lIsNumber = true;
   std::string::const_iterator it = strNum.begin();
   while (it != strNum.end())
   {
      if (!std::isdigit(*it))
      {
         lIsNumber = false;
         break;
      }
      ++it;
  }
   return lIsNumber;
}
```

Comment: I suppose that should work. It won't take the rest of the line into consideration, but that can be easily done. Why haven't I thought of this? :O